# yii multi-level ajaxLink

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm designing a 3-level menu in my website, and I use yii as the php-framework.

For example:

```
ItemA
 Item_a1
   Item_a11
   Item_a12
 Item_a2
ItemB
 ...
```

For some reasons I'd like to use ajax to generate those sub_items.

Therefore I wrote CHtml::ajaxLink("ItemA", url, ...); and it works fine to generate the second level items, i.e Item_a1, Item_a2, ....

My problem is the when I use CHtml::ajaxLink("Item_a1", url, ...); to ajax to generate the 3rd level, it can't work.

My guess is that when the second time I generate the ajaxLink by renderPartial, yii didn't inject the corresponding js-script to the view so that the link can't work.

I don't know how to fix this problem, please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely right, and there is a parameter on [renderPartial()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) which will force including the JS code to fix this. Something like this:

```
$this->renderPartial(
  '_partialview', // your menu view
  array(), // data/variables for your view
  false, // whether it should print or return the buffered output
  true, // "processOutput" - false by default, this should output your JS now
);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Oh I forgot the fourth parameters for renderPartial! Thanks!